# Java command still not found after configuring JDK environment variable correctly

Tags: java, windows, powershell, environment-variables

I do a thing to install JDK when a Windows virtual machine boot, use a cloudinit user-data to transfer a PowerShell script to the windows machine, and run the script to install JDK.

```cs
$softwares = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
$jdk = $softwares | Where-Object DisplayName -match 'Java SE Development Kit'
$java_home = $jdk.InstallLocation.Trim('\')
#$java_home = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"
$classpath = ".;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\dt.jar;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar"
$path = ";%JAVA_HOME%\bin;" + $env:Path
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("JAVA_HOME", $java_home, "machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("CLASSPATH", $classpath, "machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", $path , "machine")
```

The problem is my script installs the JDK successfully and modifies the environment variables correctly, but the command `java` still doesn't run. The path is right and the path in the registry is right，too.

[image: I am sure the path is right]

I am sure the path is right because when I modify "Path" (delete ',' in the head of "Path") by steps such as MyPC/RigthClick/Properties/Advaced/EnvironmentVariables/. And I also try to configure "Path" without ";" in the head, still can't run `java` successfully, modify "Path" by add ";", it runs well.

Comment: Just to be sure: did you run java from a command prompt, and if yes, did you open a new one after modifying the Path?

Comment: Yes，I have tried to open a new one ,and I also tried to reboot the windows VM.

Comment: Check if there's java in `%JAVA_HOME%/bin/`. Try the command `where java`.Your path shouldn't start with `;`. Try to `echo %PATH%` after your operations and check it.

Comment: Goddamn, I sohuld've post it as an answer :p

Comment: I make a mistake, I mean the Ansgar Wiechers's answer is right , sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment variables are stored in the registry. `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()` writes the given variable as a `REG_SZ` value, but for nested variables to be expanded you need a `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value.

If you want to use `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` in the PATH use `Set-ItemProperty` instead of `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable()`:

```
$regkey = 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment'
Set-ItemProperty -Path $regkey -Name 'Path' -Value $path -Type ExpandString
```

Beware that there may be other pitfalls when using nested variables in environment variables due to the order in which they're expanded. Raymond Chen described the behavior in the article [Windows Confidential: The hidden variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj853254.aspx).

Comment: There's a typo in `Set-ItemProeprty` and `The hdden variables` :3

Comment: @Nathan True. Thanks for the heads up. Fixed.

Comment: It's fixed, thank you all very much! I would read the article carefully.