# How do you source User envvars in PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell

I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-6#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing), its possible to dot source scripts in Windows PowerShell. How does one source the User's envvars instead (or which filepath are the User vars saved)?

Example.ps1:

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "C:\newapp\bin", "User")
newapp --do-something # fails until PS restart
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Environment variables are loaded at the start of a session and changes only apply to the 'in-memory' copy and are typically discarded when the session ends.  Using [Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx) can persist changes across sessions.

Comment: I'm trying to set the users $PATH in a script, source the new $PATH, then access it later in the same ps1 script without having to quit PowerShell and re-run

Comment: Setting `$env:PATH` should do unless you want to make the changes persistent, in which case this would be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/45607279/1630171.

Comment: Yes, they need to persist. I'm not sure you understand the question. I need to set it, persist, AND have it available immediately in the current PS session

Comment: Simply do both. Setting `$env:PATH` changes the PATH for the current process, `Set-ItemProperty` or `SetEnvironmentVariable()` persist the value.

Comment: Yes, but it's not available to access until you restart PowerShell, I need it immediately

Comment: Ahhh, I see now, thanks!

Comment: This will still make the script a bit of a mess. Is there no possible way to source the persistent `$env:NEWVAR` without restarting PowerShell?

Comment: When dot-sourcing a file PowerShell will execute its entire content in the current scope, so basically you just need to write the file you want to dot-source in a way that handles both persistence and changing the current environment.

Comment: I actually don't need to/can't "dot" source a file, as discussed below. As this is not possible with the User vars. I simply need the persistent User vars sourced. Any way possible...

Comment: Please take a look at my updated answer. You can use a custom function to change environment variables both ways.

Comment: I dont want to set it both ways, it will make things messier than they need to be. Is it not possible to set then source user vars?

Comment: I told you what you need to do. If you're unwilling to do it you're on your own. Have fun.

Comment: Setting the variable in the registry does not propagate it to the current process, so you have to then set it in the current process afterwards. You may not _like_ that it works that way, but that's the way it works nonetheless. (Unfortunately, wishful thinking doesn't cause features to spring into existence.)

Comment: Thank you, It works this way in *nix systems, so I wrongfully assumed the same was possible in Windows

Comment: Umm... no, it does not work this way in Unix/Linux either. Changing the environment variable in a process does not magically make that change persistent. And changing a variable the respective persistence layer (be it a file or the registry) does not magically update the variable in any running process. You'd need to actively re-read the file from that process, just like you'd need to actively re-read the value from the registry in Windows.

Comment: Yes, you can. Set the var source the new variable and not set it twice.

Comment: echo 'NEW=VAR' > ~/.profile; source ~./profile; move on

Comment: I'm pretty much aware of how variables in Linux and Unix shells work, thank you. I'll try to make this simple for you. Linux/Unix: step 1) write variable to file, step 2) dot-source file to (re-)read the variable. Windows: step 1) write variable to registry, step 2) (re-)read variable from registry.

Comment: You missed the restart the PowerShell session step

Comment: If you want to modify an environment variable from a running process and persist it at the same time you can replace the 2nd step on both *nix and Windows with setting the (in-process) variable directly to the value you wrote to the persistence layer.

Comment: Yes, you could. But you can't do the former in Windows

Comment: "Can't do the former" what? Set environment variables from dot-sourced files? That's because Windows doesn't work that way, even if PowerShell supports dot-sourcing files.

Comment: Exactly my point, yes

Comment: *You missed the restart the PowerShell session step* I didn't miss anything. You just failed to understand what I said for step 2, i.e. that you can update environment variables in a process by re-reading them from the registry. For instance: `$env:PATH = [environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')`. THAT DOES NOT REQUIRE RESTARTING POWERSHELL. A process restart is just the easiest way to refresh all environment variables.

Comment: That's helpful, but wont work in this case. Please look at the edited example

Comment: *\*sigh\** I give up. Voting to close, b/c it's become clear to me that this is an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: I refer the honorable gentleman to my first comment on the question posted some hours ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Environment variables are stored in the registry, not in a file¹, and they're loaded automatically when PowerShell starts. There's nothing to dot-source. You can display environment variables (user environment merged with the system environment) by listing the content of the `env:` PSDrive:

```
PS C:\> Get-ChildItem env:

Name                           Value
----                           -----
ALLUSERSPROFILE                C:\ProgramData
APPDATA                        C:\Users\jsmith\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles             C:\Program Files\Common Files
...
```

Environment variables differ from regular PowerShell variables in that they must be accessed via the `env` scope prefix:

```
PS C:\> $username = 'foo'    # ← PowerShell variable
PS C:\> $username
foo
PS C:\> $env:username        # ← environment variable
jsmith
```

You can modify the current environment by making changes to the variables

```
PS C:\> $env:Path += ';C:\some\folder'    # append C:\some\folder to PATH
```

or replacing them entirely:

```
PS C:\> $env:Path = 'C:\some\folder'      # set PATH to C:\some\folder
```

It's not recommended to manipulate environment variables like `$env:USERNAME`, though.

Note, however, that while you *can* modify environment variables or load them by dot-sourcing a file (using the proper prefix in the variable names) these variables are not persisted as they're applied to the process environment only.

To make persistent changes to environment variables you need to edit the values in the registry

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment' -Name 'foo' -Value 'bar' -Type String
```

or use the .Net API

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('foo', 'bar', 'User')
```

Beware that there are [pitfalls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45611804/1630171) to changing registry values via the API.

Using the [`setx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc755104%28v%3dws.11%29) commandline utility would also work, but I don't recommend that since the syntax is not as straightforward as one would like, and PowerShell doesn't need an external program in the first place.

You can also update an environment variable that was changed after the process was started by re-reading its value from the registry:

```
$env:foo = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('foo', 'User')
```

Beware, though, that Windows stores the user and system environment in different places. If you have a variable like `$env:Path` that is defined in both the user and the system environment you need to combine both values:

```
$env:Path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'Machine') + ';' +
            [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('Path', 'User')
```

If you need an environment variable both changed for the current process *and* persisted you need to do both actions: change `$env:VARIABLE` and write the changed variable back to the registry. If you need to do this more than once, wrapping the two actions in a custom function might be advisable, e.g. like this:

```
function Set-EnvVariable {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [String]$Name,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $Value,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [String]$Type = 'String'
    )

    if (Test-Path -LiteralPath "env:$Name") {
        Set-Item "env:$Name" -Value $Value
    } else {
        New-Item -Path 'env:' -Name $Name -Value $value
    }

    Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKCU:\Environment' -Name $Name -Value $Value -Type $Type
}
```

---

¹ Well, technically the part of the registry that contains (among other things) the user environment variables *is* stored in a file `ntuser.dat` in the user's profile directory. However, that's nothing one could dot-source in PowerShell.

Comment: Why can't you dot source the ntuser.dat ?

Comment: Because it's a binary file that contains the user hive of the registry. The `ntuser.dat` of each user logging in is loaded into the registry under `HKU\<USER_SID>` and is also displayed to the respective user under `HKCU`. Environment variables are just a very small part of that file (what you see under `HKCU\Environment`).

Comment: This is helpful, but doesnt answer the question. I need to set the persistent `$env:VAR` then access it in the same script without restarting PowerShell, there must be a way to do this?