# PM2 command not running under PowerShell script

Tags: node.js, powershell, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have following command in my Windows instance user data in AWS. I can see pm2 env variable is setup but in next line in PowerShell does not start pm2 server. I am running pm2 under system profile NOT under any user profile.

See below code:

```
$myvar = "D:\Mycode"
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PM2_HOME", "C:\etc\.pm2", "Machine")

& 'C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming\npm\pm2.cmd' start $myvar"\app.js" |
    Out-File D:\debug.txt -Append
```

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Now, where have I seen a question like this before ...? [Oh, wait!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51246716/1630171)

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable(...)` doesnt impact the current shells environment variables, so the `PM2_HOME` variable will not exist when you call `pm2.cmd`.

A simple fix is after you call `SetEnvironmentVariable`, use the following command to then retrieve that value, and create that variable in the current shell:

```
$env:PM2_HOME = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PM2_HOME","Machine");
```

This is only required during the userdata script as all future sessions will have this environment variable (ie environment variables are loaded when a session starts).

An alternative would be to invoke a new instance of `powershell.exe` (or even `cmd.exe`) to start `pm2.cmd` - as this would create a new session, which would receive the new environment variable.