# How to execute CMD file to set environment variable automatically using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, cmd, command-line

I want to set an environment variable automatically, without executing the cmd first, then echo the environment to show the value of environment variable.

I tried this code, I store the value as cmd file that I want to set as environment variable. If I want to show the environment value, I have to execute the cmd file first.

```bsh
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $FilePath,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Key,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Variable_Name,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] [string] $Store
)

$Found = $False
$FileContents = switch -File $FilePath {
    $Key    { $Found = $True }
    default {
        if ($Found) {
            $_.Substring(1);
            break
        }
    }
}
$FileContents

$Path_Store = $Store
$Output = "set" + " " + $Variable_Name + "=" + $FileContents |
          Out-File $Path_Store\$Variable_Name.cmd -Encoding Ascii
```

My expectation, once I execute the PowerShell script, I can directly show the environment variable.

Comment: You are not setting an environment variable anywhere in this code.. Besides that, isn't this [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470479/environment-variable-can-set-but-can-not-print-if-only-once-executing-in-powersh) you asked earlier?

Comment: Any changes are lost when Powershell (or any other program) exits.

Comment: You're misunderstanding how environment variables work. Modifying an environment variable in the registry does not make running processes re-read their environment. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51247258/1630171).