# Creating Environment Variable Through Powershell

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, environment-variables

I am trying to create Environment variable for machine through powershell and passing the variables at run-time but It's not taking the variables.
Powershell file: env_variable.ps1

```
Param (
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  [String] $VAULT_TEXT,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]  [String] $VAL
 )
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("$VAULT_TEXT","$VAL",[System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine)
```

Trying to trigger through Powershell:

```
$vault_text='IAndAAuth'
$val = get-content 'C:\vault\service_acct_pass'
C:\vault\env_variable.ps1 -VAULT_TEXT "$vault_text" -VAL "$val"
```

Result is coming like this: Key:VAULT_TEXT, Value:VAL in environments value.

Can you please help me in this.

Comment: It works for me. How do you read the result? Did you start a new session? [Does it concern a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45607279/1701026)

Comment: BTW, there should be no need to quote the variables as they are already defined `[string]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method seems right and should be working. If you like try doing it the old way by creating a registry key for you environment variable.

User

```
New-ItemProperty "HKCU:\Envrionment" -Name "your variable name" -Value "your value"
```

Machine

```
New-ItemProperty "HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" -Name "your variable name" -Value "your value"
```